# OnClick event does't called after scrolling with CollapsingToolbarLayout.

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, android-design-library, android-scroll

I've implemented parallax effect with `CollapsingToolbarLayout` and found an issue: When I click `RecyclerView` item immediately after the scrolling and parallax effect, the `onClick` event does't called, but `onTouch` event of `RecyclerView` is called.
 If you wait few seconds (without clicking), it works well.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsingToolbarLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="250dp"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:src="@drawable/img_stub"/>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"/>
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

The problem appears when i add `app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll"` to CollapsingToolbarLayout.
I think it can depends on scrim animation...

Comment: Hello Dima, I have exactly the same issue, took me several days before I have narrowed it down to this problem. Did you find a workaround for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've created an issue for this bug.
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/70883270

This is thе answer of support library developers team:
"Our engineering team has fixed this issue. It will be available in a future support lib release."

Answer (score 2):

It seems this is a bug in `NestedScrollView`. You can workaround this by using the `FixedAppBarLayoutBehaviour` from [here](https://gist.github.com/chrisbanes/8391b5adb9ee42180893300850ed02f2).

And add it to your `AppBarLayout` like this:

```
 <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_height="..."
        android:layout_width="..."
        app:layout_behavior="your.package.FixAppBarLayoutBehavior">
```

Comment: Today, I was solving this issue as well for whole evening. There was delay (strangely just on some phones) between UI started to register OnClick events on button after scrolling when NestedScrollView was involved. Workaround provided by @Petr does the trick for me. Dik za tip :).